# How can I connect to the Isolation bridge on a network protected by a lock?

Tags: uplink

How can I bypass through those locks?

I a currently stuck on this mission, am I missing something?
What supposedly I should do with those locks also with those two on top on the right side that is both connected on computer terminals?

I can connect to those PC but I can't connect to the lock.

[image: Eclipse LAN]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you haven't connected using the modem to access the Isolation bridge.

You should be able to find the phone number for the modem on a terminal on the network. Connect to that address and you will be behind the lock and will be able to access the isolation bridge.

Comment: I logged in to every computers in that network except the main server and I couldn't find any phone numbers for the modem. I can't connect to the main server since it is guarded by those 3 locks on top.

Comment: I finally did it, just forced my way into it using a LAN Force then I got the number to the modem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get to (and use) the modem without LAN-Force:

- The component just before the modem, surrounded by white dots, is an *Isolation Bridge*. It controls 2 locks, the ones surrounded by yellow dots: one is locked and the other is unlocked.
- When you connect to an Isolation Bridge and Enable / Disable it, it toggles *both* locks simultaneously: unlocking one and locking the other.
- The lock to the left of the Isolation Bridge is currently *locked*, and its label says *"unlocks"*, because that's what will happen when you change the Isolation Bridge mode. That lock prevents you from reaching the top left lock.
- The lock below the Isolation Bridge is *unlocked*, so its label says *"locks"*, and it lets you access the Isolation Bridge and the Modem.
- Notice that if you toggle the Isolation Bridge now, you will lock yourself out, losing access to the Isolation Bridge! So *don't* do that yet!
- Go to the Modem and *connect* to it. That's where its external access phone number is located ;)
- Use an *IP Lookup* to add the phone number to your connection list.
- Now you can connect to the LAN using this entry, and your starting position will be the Modem.
- Now you can safely toggle the Isolation Bridge to gain access to the last lock.